# Is it possible to safely use eval in a web worker to execute arbitrary user code?

Tags: javascript, eval, web-worker

Is it possible to offload custom user code that would be evaled to a Web Worker in a safe way?

The "only communicate" with strings feature of the Web Workers look promising but eval'ing user code is pretty much always dangerous in interesting ways.

I can't find much information on the web about it. Would there be a good way to do that either client side or with some server-side sanitizing or something else?

Answer (score 5):

Web workers can't change the DOM, so they can't create new elements and create an XSS attack this way. However, they can create XMLHttpRequests, so they can reach and request data from anything that follows the same-origin-policy.

As long as you sanitize the messages to and from the worker you should be safe. Just allow specific strings, objects or integers and block other kinds of messages.

Also, if the Web Workers are only per-user and not being distributed between users, they won't allow your user to do anything they couldn't do already with the developer consoles.

See also:

- MDN: [Using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: If you hit F12 and write a ajax request from the console you're making requests to the server. You don't need a worker to do that, just a console.

Comment: @devundef: Dan didn't state who will execute the Web Worker later. It could either be the author of the web worker, or someone completely different. I assumed the second one. Btw, if I hit F12, nothing happens. Strange times, huh? ;)

Comment: Could I fix the XMLHttpRequest issue by removing that function when I setup the worker?

Comment: Is your plan store the user script on server and run it later?

Comment: @devundef, correct. I plan for the code to be safe to be run by any user later.

Comment: @Bergi covered the issues on his answers. Any gap in your code will is  a potential entry point for exploitation.

Comment: @Dan: That could work. If you use `window.XMLHttpRequest = null` it would essentially remove `XMLHttpRequest` from that browsers API (you need to look up whether this works in IE and Chrome, works in Firefox).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on two factors:

- Which user created the code? Every user is allowed to execute custom code in *his own* browser anyway, you can't hinder them. You can "give" code entered by the current user "full privileges".

  If the code is created by other, possibly malicious users, you'd need to watch out. WebWorkers can execute Ajax requests, which might be a possible security hole because of the credentials. And any infinite loops and co are never nice to have.
- Your GUI communicates with the WebWorker, and responds to events from it. How many harm can a WebWorkers message do to your application? You will need to restrict that.

Comment: "Ajax requests, which might be a possible security hole because of the credentials": This is only true, when cookies are used, right? i.e. when we attach a JWT token to each http call in our app (and don't pass it to the web-worker), it is not an issue.

Comment: @TmTron Yes, I was probably referring to CSRF. It is an issue with cookies, but also with intranet sites where "the client is in the local network" is part of the credential. And with JWTs you're not necessarily safe either, since these are typically held in Web Storage to which a normal worker has access as well.